# how can we mount root file system in android10

Tags: android-source, android-10.0, rootfs

I can able to mount system partition.

I could not able to mount root partition.

getting error like this :

1|console:/ # mount -o rw,remount /

[ 3640.420613] EXT4-fs (dm-0): couldn't mount RDWR because of unsupported optional features (4000)

[ 3640.434479] EXT4-fs (dm-0): couldn't mount RDWR because of unsupported optional features (4000)

'/dev/block/dm-0' is read-only

console:/ # [ 3903.028999] WLDEV-ERROR)

Comment: try,adb root
adb remount
adb disable-verity
adb reboot

Comment: How did you solve this issue? I am also stuck with same. I added BOARD_KERNEL_CMDLINE += CONFIG_OVERLAY_FS=y
  in my BoardConfig. but it did not work.